# SQLite refuces to be set to WAL with Microsoft.Data.Sqlite .Net 7 in C#

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, wal

I am unable to set WAL mode for SQLite programmatically.
My code is called when I create the database file

```
var conn = new SqliteConnection(_connectionString);
            await using(conn.ConfigureAwait(false))
            {
                await conn.OpenAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                var trans = await conn.BeginTransactionAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                await using(trans.ConfigureAwait(false))
                {
                    var command = conn.CreateCommand();
                    await using(command.ConfigureAwait(false))
                    {
                        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        command.CommandText = $"PRAGMA journal_mode = WAL;";
                        await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                    }
                    var command2 = conn.CreateCommand();
                    await using(command2.ConfigureAwait(false))
                    {
                        command2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        command2.CommandText = $"PRAGMA wal_autocheckpoint=1000;";
                        await command2.ExecuteNonQueryAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                    }
                    trans.Commit();
                }
                //Set Settings
            }
```

When I open the Database again the journal_mode is DELETE. However wal_autocheckpoint is set to 1000 correctly.
Using DB Browser for SQLite and running the same command works.
I tried anything I could think of. I even splited the two PRAGMAs into seperate commands. Originaly They where packed into one

`$"PRAGMA journal_mode = WAL;{Environment.NewLine}PRAGMA wal_autocheckpoint=1000;"`

Any ideas?

I am expecting that after running the code and opening the SQLite Database that the database is in WAL mode.

Comment: Change to WAL mode before you start the transaction; right after you open the connection.

Answer (score 0):

[@Mark Benningfield](https://stackoverflow.com/users/500276/mark-benningfield) hit the spot.
After moving BeginTransactionAsync after the PRAGMA journal_mode = WAL; command the journal mode was set correctly.

Thanks